# Excel: manipulation over sorted sequence of numbers

Tags: excel

[image]

column `id_0` has sorted numbers (some of them repeated) and in column `id_1`, I need to multiple the value of `id_0` by `10000` and increment by `1` if there are sequence of the same value. If not then increment should start from `1`.
In the table, you can see `10001, 10002, and 10003` and after increment initialized and started from 1 again: `20001, 20002`.

How can I implement it by using standard function inside cell in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this into the first row of `id_1`. So, if the `id_0` header cell is `Cell A1`, place this into `Cell B2`.

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,A2*10000+1)
```

This compares the `id_0` cell for the row with the row above it and performs the desired calculation.